# Jquery: Why if I had a jquery trigger inside in other, the second when occurs fire multiple times?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the follow code to make toggle a vertical dropdown. The problem happens when I do mouseenter several times in 'ul > li > a' and after select de submenu and I enter inside it, the second trigger fires multiple times.

```
$('nav > ul > li > a').on('mouseenter',function(e){
    var currentID = this;
    var index = $('ul.topnav > li > a').index(this);
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    $('nav ul ul').css('margin-top',(38*parseInt(index)));

    $(this).parent().find('ul').on('mouseenter',function(e){
        //fire several times
        console.log('hover');           
        $(currentID).addClass('selected');
    }).on('mouseleave',function(e){
        $(currentID).removeClass('selected');
        //fire several times
        console.log('end hover');
    });

}).on('mouseleave',function(e){
    $(this).removeClass('selected');
);
```

Comment: Because it's being re-bound every time the top one gets executed, resulting in `n` mouseenter events on the ul where `n` is the number of times you've triggered the top event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are binding events to the subelements of this each time you hover `nav > ul > li > a`.

Try this:

```
$('nav > ul > li > a').each(function(e){

    $(this).on('mouseenter',function(e){
        var index = $('ul.topnav > li > a').index(this);
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        $('nav ul ul').css('margin-top',(38*parseInt(index)));
    }).on('mouseleave',function(e){
        $(this).removeClass('selected');
    );

    var currentID = this;

    $(this).parent().find('ul').on('mouseenter',function(e){
        //fire several times
        console.log('hover');           
        $(currentID).addClass('selected');
    }).on('mouseleave',function(e){
        $(currentID).removeClass('selected');
        //fire several times
        console.log('end hover');
    });

});
```

Comment: This is the solution. Tanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Every time the outer `mouseenter` callback is executed, it attaches new, additional event handlers to the `ul` (which will do the same thing as the previously attached handlers.

When The mouse then enters that `ul`, all the attached event handlers are called.

You only should attach the event handler once, not on every `mouseenter`.